# Specialize Inheritance Construct

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the classes A and B where B inherits from A. Both classes are abstract and implement some methods and some methods are abstract, forcing the specialized implementation to implement those functions.

Now, specialized A (specA) inherits from A and specialized B (specB) inherits from B. As a result (tried in C#) it seems like specB does not inherit from specA - specA test = specBInstance; won't work (which makes sense, because specB does not inherit from specA...). Question is how to design the whole thing, so that specB at least acts like it would directly inherit from specA?

The result should be like this - it is like spezializing a whole hierarchical construct and not only one class...

```
A --<-- specA
|
^         ^ need inheritance here
|
B --<-- specB
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't, how could it? SpecB must inherit from SpecA in order to use SpecA's methods, howerver this looks quite complex. What are you trying to model?

Comment: Yeah, but SpecB cannot inherit from SpecA, because it already inherits from B. It's a structure for CAD-models (structure and structure functions are the same for all models, but the implementation of a few function differs from model to model)

Comment: That's like saying a cat and a dog are both animals, so why doesn't the cat inherit all the dog's features (and I suppose conversely the dog must then inherit all the cat's features... except then we are stuck in some sort of infinite loop of dog-cat hybridization).

Comment: work adding an `interface` help here?

Comment: @cbp it's more like a "babydog" inherits from a "dog" and a "Newfoundlander" inherits from a "dog" and a "Newfoundlander-Baby" inherits from "babydog" and the "Newfoundlander-Baby" should still be a dog...

Comment: @martybourque Yeah, you can't do it. That's multiple inheritance. You can use an interface, but the interface doesn't have any actual functionality so it's not really going to help. You need to use some sort of 'composition' pattern.

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.

You should probably look into *favouring composition over inheritance*. The functionality of specA that you want specB to have access to can be broken out as a separate class and injected where required.

Reading your comment about the CAD models, you can make use of something like the 'Strategy Pattern' - break out your functions as separate classes. There are many different variations on the code, but you can achieve things like this:

```
public class Animal
{
   // In this case we pass the sound strategy to the method. However you could also
   // get the strategy from a protected abstract method, or you could even use some sort
   // of IOC container.
   public void MakeSound(SoundStrategy soundStrategy)
   {
       soundStrategy.MakeSound();
   }
}

public class Bark : SoundStrategy
{
    public override void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof");
    }
}

public class Meow : SoundStrategy
{
    public override void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Meow");
    }
}

public class BarkLoudly : Bark
{
    public override void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WOOF");
    }
}
```